# Client side validation gem conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, client-side-validation

I am working on `rails 3.2.12` using client side validation and client side validation mongoid. I got in some issues probably some one can help.

1. I have 2 fields. I want to validate the presence of 2nd field if the
   value of 1st field is greater then 0.
2. How to validate the checkbox ?
3. How to validate the "date_select" drop down.

I have tried:

```
validates_presence_of :source_other_income_amount, :if => :condition_testing?
```

And:

```
def condition_testing?
  !(:other_income_amount == 0)
end
```

But the field doesn't validate when other income is not 0.

Comment: Hi - have you had a go at it yourself? Did you look into the available validations to see what might fit? what did you come up with (even if it didn't work)?

Comment: Yes. for first i tried using :if but failed. and cant find anything for checkbox and date_select.

Comment: It would be really helpful to us if you showed us the code you tried (even if it is broken)... along with the errors that you got. Sometimes it's easier for us to adjust your code than to write new stuff from scratch. (of course sometimes it isn't, but it's good to give it to us anyway)

Comment: Especially because it'll help us know which kind of client-side validation you  are using :)

Comment: bleh - sorry, formatting in comments is awful - can you add that to your question please :)

Comment: Yah.. I have edited my question.

Comment: aha, and now I can see a problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

This bit is ok:

```
validates_presence_of :source_other_income_amount, :if => :condition_testing?
```

but this bit has a bug:

```
def condition_testing?
  !(:other_income_amount == 0)
end
```

At the point where you are inside of "condition_testing?" you are a real instance of a model, and so you need to use `other_income_amount`, not the symbol `:other_income_amount`

Try:

```
def condition_testing?
  other_income_amount != 0
end
```

note: this might also not work... you will need to see what you actually have in "other_income_amount" at this point.
it might already be a boolean (true/false) rather than 0/1